# What is the total number of all abelian groups of order $675$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Recently I came across the following question:

> What is the total number of all abelian groups of order $675$?

I know how to find out number of abelian groups up to isomorphism. But I have no idea how to approach this question.

If anybody has any idea then please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: They had to mean up to isomorphism.  Otherwise the question is meaningless, as you can relabel the elements to whatever you want, to whatever cardinality of infinity you want.

Comment: That is what it means, *up to isomorphism*.

Comment: i was thinking the same that the question does not make sense. I can make any number of groups just by relabeling the elements. I wanted to make sure that i am not missing something. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Can you use the Fundamental Theorem of Finitely Generated Abelian Groups?

Comment: $675=3^3\cdot 5^2$.

Comment: @shaun That is what we use to find number of abelian groups upto 'isomorphism'.

Comment: And that is the only thing that has sense as stated by @Alan

Comment: Yes, @user684646; that's one of its uses and it's why I mentioned it. As others have said, the question has "up to isomorphism" implicitly.

Comment: Thanks i got the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** By the Fundamental Theorem of Finitely Generated Abelian Groups, the number of abelian groups of order $n=p_1^{n_1}\dots p_k^{n_k}$ up to isomorphism is the product of the number of partitions of each of the $n_i$.